# How can I pass property as parameter in MSTest DataRow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a DataTestMethod in my unit test using MSTest, and I have a string property in my constructor, let's say I have this code for example:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("test")] 
[DataRow(stringproperty)] // How is this?

public void TestMethod(string test) {
    Assert.AreEqual("test", test);
}
```

Is it possible to pass a property as parameter in DataRow?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: NO!!!!. Attributes need constants values.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12):

Yes if you use the DynamicDataAttribute

```
[DynamicData("TestMethodInput")]
[DataTestMethod]
public void TestMethod(string test)
{
    Assert.AreEqual("test", test);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestMethodInput
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new object[] { stringproperty },
            new object[] { "test" }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct but still ugly technic.

Answer (score 4):

As a refinement, use

```c#
[DynamicData(nameof(TestMethodInput))]
```

instead of `[DynamicData("TestMethodInput")]`.

This later in C# introduced `nameof` keyword ensures that all renaming refactorings are followed and naming errors are caught at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
private List<string> testData=new List<string>();
testData.Add("test");
testData.Add("test1");

private IEnumerable<object[]> ListOfTestData =>
    new List<string[]> 
    {
        new[] {testData[0]},
        new[] {testData[1]}
    };

[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData (nameof (ListOfTestData))]
public void TestMethod(string test) 
{
    Assert.AreEqual("test", test);
}
```

Source: https://dev.to/frannsoft/mstest-v2---new-old-kid-on-the-block

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where it's easy to see how to map multiple dynamic values and multiple test cases.

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestMethodInput
{
    get
    {
        ListNode t13 = new(4);
        ListNode t12 = new(2, t13);
        ListNode t11 = new(1, t12);

        ListNode t23 = new(4);
        ListNode t22 = new(3, t23);
        ListNode t21 = new(1, t22);
        return new[]
        {
            new object[] {t13, "4, "},
            new object[] {t12, "2, 4, "},
            new object[] {t11, "1, 2, 4, "},
            new object[] {t21, "1, 3, 4, "}
        };
    }
}


[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestMethodInput))]
public void TestListNodeToString(ListNode node, string expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, node.ToString());
}
```