# Using List<string> type as DataRow Parameter

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, parameters, attributes

How can we pass a `List<string>` to a `DataRow` parameter in `[DataTestMethod]`

I am trying something like:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(new List<string>() {"Iteam1"})]
[TestCategory(TestCategories.UnitTest)]
public void MyTest(IEnumerable<string> myStrings)
{
// ...    
}
```

I am getting a compile error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Is it even possible to pass List like this?

Comment: can you pass an array instead?

Comment: @JohnB Yes, I can pass array of string, but I tried that and wasn't working either, could show how I would pass for the example in question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ...- Create an attribute of type array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859094/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-create-an-attribute-of)

Comment: Please show us your attempt using array of strings (in your question).

Comment: `DynamicData` would be the attribute to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298140/how-can-i-pass-property-as-parameter-in-mstest-datarow

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As the error message mentions, you cannot use `List`s in attributes but you can use arrays.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(new string[] { "Item1" })]
[TestCategory(TestCategories.UnitTest)]
public void MyTest(string[] myStrings)
{
    // ...  
}
```

To really use a `List` or any other type you can use `DynamicDataAttribute`.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetTestData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
[TestCategory(TestCategories.UnitTest)]
public void MyTest(IEnumerable<string> myStrings)
{
    // ...  
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData()
{
    yield return new object[] { new List<string>() { "Item1" } };
}
```

The method or property given to the `DynamicDataAttribute` must return an `IEnumerable` of object arrays. These object arrays represent the parameters to be passed to your test method.

If you always have a fixed number of items in your list you can avoid using lists altogether

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("Item1", "Item2")]
[TestCategory(TestCategories.UnitTest)]
public void MyTest(string string1, string string2)
{
    // ...  
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I found another cool way to do it with arrays!  :)

The `DataRow` in MS Test allows you to pass `params` parameters.  These will pass into the array in the test method signature.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(true, "")]
    [DataRow(true, "", "")]
    [DataRow(true, "", "", "0")]
    [DataRow(true, "", "", "", "1")]
    [DataRow(true, "", "1", "", "0", "")]
    [DataRow(false, "1")]
    [DataRow(false, "", "1")]
    [DataRow(false, "", "", "1")]
    [DataRow(false, "", "", "1", "1")]
    [DataRow(false, "1", "1", "1", "1")]
    public void IsSparseRow(bool expected, params string[] row)
    {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        var actual = ExcelFileHelpers.IsSparseRow(row);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```