# Unit test for two string arrays

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

The below data row in my unit test throws an error message when two string arrays follow after one another, but not when I place another data type in-between.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    // invalid
    [DataRow(new string[] { }, new string[] { })]
    // valid
    [DataRow(new string[] { }, 8, new string[] { })]
    public void TestMethod(string[] input, string[] output)
    {
        var solution = new Program();

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(output, solution.Method(input));
    }
}
```

And I get the following error (on line 6), an attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type. I'm defining the array in constructor, so how is it not constant? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In an attribute you cannot instantiate variables, in an attribute everything must be known at compile time

Comment: So please explain @user449689 to me why it doesn't complain when I throw an extra data type in-between those arrays?

Comment: you can add as many extra data types you want, but your code will not compile

Comment: If I comment out line 6, it runs tests without a problem as long as I add int variableName in the TestMethod, but I don't want to be doing that @user449689. I can also do `Assert.AreEqual(new string[] { }, solution.Method(new string[] { }));` but then it gets messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in the `DataRow` attr is the `params object[] moreData`.

You are passing `new string[] { }` which differs from `object[]` this is why you are getting an error.

Try using this:

```
[DataRow(new string[] { }, new object[] { new string[] { } })]
public void TestMethod(string[] input, string[] output) {}
```

It would map objects array to strings correctly.

But you might consider using the `DynamicData` attribute to pass complex values.

Answer (score 0):

What is crazy is that the two following methods works :

```
[DataRow(new string[] { "Item1" }, "1", new string[] { "Item1" })]
public void MyTest(string[] argArray, string expectedResult, string[] expectedResultArray)
{
    // ... 
}
```

and

```
[DataRow("1", new string[] { "Item1" }, new string[] { "Item1" })]
public void MyTest(string arg1, string[] argArray, string[] expectedResultArray)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Edit : best answer is here (second one) : [Using List<string> type as DataRow Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199965/using-liststring-type-as-datarow-parameter)